# Extract email from string variable using find()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Do you guys know how I'll be able to extract an email from a string using find()

```py
info = "message email@gmail.com"
```

I want to be able to get the entire "email@gmail.com" and output only that to the screen.

Comment: It's looks like it is string not a list.

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya yeah.. sorry i had meant to put string

Comment: have you tried using regular expression?

Comment: use simply, info.split(' ')[1]

Comment: @Juhil Assuming that `message` will probably contain spaces, `info.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]` would be safer.

Comment: @deceze agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using regex:

```
import re
emails_list = re.findall('\S+@\S+', info)
```